# Tutorials on How to set up a linux system from scratch

Tags: hard-drive, usb, linux-kernel

I have a USB hard disk. I want to run a simple application on Linux. Kinldy tell me the tutorial links where i can find info on how to build the bootloader, kernel and roof file system from scratch into the USB hard disk. Also tell me the tutorials on how to boot linux from USB hard disk once the system is ready.

Answer (score 3):

I also recommend LFS. I've built it many times before, and it is *insanely* fast. I built a CLI rendering engine, and it was 100MB (unstripped; I could get it to around 10-20, but I'm too lazy). It's a pain to build, though, as it takes around 8 hours on my computer.

The nice thing is that you can customize anything to fit your needs. I've heard of 3 MB webservers being built with LFS (the link is in the post above).

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for LFS.  Not such a pain anymore, as they have a live CD that helps you prebuild a chrooted environment.  Documents talk you through it all.  No other way to **really** learn about Linux.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Live_USB_stick

http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/liveusb.xml

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Answer (score 1):

[Linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)